# Normal - RPN conversion

Tags: java

Is there any way to interpret "normal" mathematical notation into Reverse Polish Notation(RPN)..?
 eg
1)   2 + 3*4 - 1 = 234*+1-
2)   5 *(4-8) = 548-*

U can assume  that BODMAS rule is followed and that inner brackets have to be calculated first etc.. i mean the normal maths to be applied here.. the answer should be in postfix notation..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So-called "normal" is rigorously called [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation).  There are also [prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) and [postfix notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), the latter being RPN.

The typical rearrangement of notation is done by constructing a parse tree and traversing specifically for the arrangement needed.

Here are some descriptions of how to do it:  [a](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118070107/http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm)  [b](https://web.archive.org/web/20100826044842/http://www.spsu.edu/cs/faculty/bbrown/web_lectures/postfix/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes; the [**shunting yard algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) defines how to do this.

Each time you read a number, put it onto the *output queue*. Each time you read an operator, put it on the *operator stack*. These two structures form the basis of the algorithm.

Comment: The shunting yard is the way to go.  Here is a code snippet of me taking an expression from infix to postfix, then evaluating the postfix expression: http://pastebin.com/f13bf7f70